# AJAX call in Scala Play: Data not transfered

Tags: javascript, ajax, playframework, playframework-2.0, google-oauth

I'm about to implement a Login using Google OAuth. I followed the [official Google docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow)
The client does get a token from the Google server. But whenever I try to send it back to my server to store it, I do not seem to get data from the AJAX call. Here is my code:

```
function signInCallback(authResult) { //called when client has confirmed the Login dialog
if (authResult['code']) {
    // Hide the sign-in button now that the user is authorized, for example:
    $('#signinButton').attr('style', 'display: none');
    console.log("signinCallback. Send code to server:")
    console.log("Code = "+ authResult['code']);
    console.log("performing AJAX call now...\n\n")
    // Send the code to the server
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:9000/storeauthcode',
        contentType: 'application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8',
    success: function(result) {
    // Handle or verify the server response.
      console.log("AJAX call --> success");
      console.log(result)

    },
    processData: false,
    data: authResult['code']
    });
} else {
    //There was an error.
    console.log("AJAX call failed.")
}
```

I created a line in my routes file:

```
POST        /storeauthcode        controllers.Application.storeAuthCode
```

The method on the server:

```
  def storeAuthCode = Action { request =>
    Ok("storeauthcode called with queryString = "+request.rawQueryString)
  }
```

The following is a console output of my Chrome browser:

```
hello.js:2 Welcome to your Play application's JavaScript!
(index):67 signinCallback. Send code to server:  
(index):68 Code = <token deleted for privacy reasons>
(index):69 performing AJAX call now...


(index):77 AJAX call --> success
(index):78 storeauthcode called with queryString =
```

So although my browser gets a token back, I cannot store it on the server, because I don't get any data back.

```
  Ok("storeauthcode called with queryString = "+request.body.asJson)
```

is also empty.

This one here also delivers an empty result:

```
 def storeAuthCode = Action { request =>
    Ok("storeauthcode called with queryString = "+request.getQueryString("data"))
 }
```

Comment: What happens if you return `request.body`?  You have no query string and your POST isn't of a JSON content type which explains why neither of those return anything.

Comment: I get: AnyContentAsRaw(RawBuffer(inMemory=1, backedByTemporaryFile=null))

Comment: The raw buffer is not empty (contains 77 elements). But how do I extract the "code" I've sent via the AJAX call?

Comment: I guess the problem is contentType: 'application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8'. Google returns an octet-stream instead of a String. so I can't extract it like a normal key value pair. So the actual question is: How do I convert an octet stream on my server to a string or, how do I convert an octet stream in Javascript?